# Yii2 REST DB Geometry field serialization

Tags: json, rest, yii2, spatial

I have a table in mySQL with fields of GEOMETRY and POLYGON types. And the Yii2 RESTful app. Here is a standart ActiveController:

```
<?php

namespace backend\modules\v1\controllers;

use common\models\Geo;

class GeoController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'common\models\Geo';
}
```

When I have any records in my table with spatial data JSON response breaks with message:

```
code: 5
file: "/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseJson.php"
line: 120
message: "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded."
name: "Exception"
```

Should I write custom json serializer or somehow override ActiveProvider select with something like "AsText(geometry_field_name)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the issue was solved by extending ActiveQuery class with adding additional column using SQL command AsText(`geomery_field_name`) as `geometry_text`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change field types supported by JSON (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_data_types.htm).

For example, if you use MySQL field with type CHAR, you will get the same error